# paintComponent not called when calling JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, paintcomponent, jfilechooser

I'm trying to load a background image with a JFileChooser, but when the operation ends, the paintcomponent() method is not called as expected. 
[EDIT] for this reason, instead of having a red ball over the background image, I have the red ball only.

I read in several other topics that the instance of my Mappa Object should be added to the frame:
[Why is paint()/paintComponent() never called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676187/why-is-paint-paintcomponent-never-called)
[paintComponent not being called at the right time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441700/paintcomponent-not-being-called-at-the-right-time)
[PaintComponent is not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484359/paintcomponent-is-not-being-called)

But this does not solve my problem: I created a JScrollPane that gets my component in the constructor and linked the JScrollPane and added it in the main frame with

`frmEditor.getContentPane().add(scrollabile, BorderLayout.CENTER);`

This is the code of the main Gui

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class Gui implements ActionListener {

    private JFrame frmEditor;

    Mappa content;
    private JMenuItem mntmSfondo;
    private JScrollPane scrollabile;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Gui window = new Gui();
                    window.frmEditor.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Gui() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frmEditor = new JFrame();
        frmEditor.setFont(UIManager.getFont("TextArea.font"));
        frmEditor.setBounds(50, 50, 1024, 768);
        frmEditor.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmEditor.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JPanel panelTile = new JPanel();
        panelTile.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JPanel panelStrum = new JPanel();

        panelStrum.setLayout(new GridLayout(15, 2));

        content = new Mappa(null);
        content.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(150, 150));
        scrollabile = new JScrollPane(content);
        scrollabile
                .setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollabile
                .setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        frmEditor.getContentPane().add(scrollabile, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        inizializzaMenu();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the menu.
     */
    private void inizializzaMenu() {

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        frmEditor.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
        mnFile.setFont(UIManager.getFont("TextArea.font"));

        JMenu mnAltro = new JMenu("Modify");
        mnAltro.setFont(UIManager.getFont("TextArea.font"));
        menuBar.add(mnAltro);

        mntmSfondo = new JMenuItem("Load Background");
        mntmSfondo
                .setIcon(new ImageIcon(
                        Gui.class
                                .getResource("/com/sun/java/swing/plaf/windows/icons/TreeOpen.gif")));
        mntmSfondo.setFont(UIManager.getFont("TextArea.font"));
        mntmSfondo.addActionListener(this);
        mnAltro.add(mntmSfondo);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if (source == mntmSfondo) {
            JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser("tuttiSfondi");
            int result = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                try {
                    content = new Mappa(file);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }
            if (result == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
            }
        }
    }

}
```

while this is the code of the class Mappa, that I would like to use to load the background from the JFileChooser.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Mappa extends JPanel {

    Image immagine;

    public Mappa(File fileImmagine) {

        if (fileImmagine != null ) {
            BufferedImage img = null;
            try {
                img = ImageIO.read(new File(fileImmagine.getPath()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            this.immagine = img;
        }
        repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.clearRect(0, 0, 4000, 4000);
        g.drawImage(immagine, 0, 0, null);

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillOval(170, 170, 150, 150);

        System.out.println("Called Repaint() on Mappa");

    }


}
```

The problem is not in an incorrect image path, since it loads if I set the path on the Mappa class "manually", by giving the path instead of using `new File(fileImmagine.getPath())` in the `ImageIO.read`, but that  paintComponent is called only once, when the constructor of Mappa is called from the Gui class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set the background, you only allocate the new `Mappa` instance, but not actually adding it to any container. Try adding the following:

```
scrollabile.setViewportView(content);
```

Or instead, replace an image in the `Mappa` class. Ie:

```
public void setImage(File file) throws IOException {
    this.immagine = ImageIO.read(file);
    repaint();
}
```

Also, in `paintComponent()`, you could use panel dimensions to fill the whole area:

```
g.drawImage(immagine, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
```

And don't forget to use a valid `ImageObserver` as `JPanel` implements one.

Comment: I tried adding `scrollable.setViewportView(content);` after and before the `frmEditor.getContentPane().add(scrollabile, BorderLayout.CENTER);` without any success. 
Vandale's suggestion of adding a setImage function on the Mappa class actually solved the problem, thank you!!

Comment: @Kaeel, the idea was to call `scrollabile.setViewportView(content);` inside `actionPerformed()` right after you re-allocate `Mappa`. But replacing the image in the existing `Mappa` is simpler.

Comment: I just tried it; it does work as well and I also learned a new thing. 
I'm sorry I still don't have enuogh reputation to upvote both of you, I'll come back on this question and do that when I'll reach 15 reputation!

Comment: @Kaeel glad it worked out! :) Consider using `setImage()` approach instead, as reallocating and replacing components is more expensive.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't actually modifying the `Mapa` instance that you've added to the frame. The line

```
content = new Mappa(file);
```

in `actionPerformed()` doesn't change the panel in the frame, it reassigns the local variable only. You should instead put a method such as `updateImage()` in `Mapa` that will update the image that `Mapa` displays. You will also need to call `repaint()` after this so that it redraws the new image.

Comment: Thank you, it seems this was the actual problem with the code. I created an updateImage method in the `Mappa` class and called it from the GUI with something like this `content.setImage(file);`